# Kivy refuses to install on python 3.8.5 on windows 10

Tags: python, kivy

here is the error:

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'D:\AndroidCalc\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\runke\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bibmt8p5\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\runke\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bibmt8p5\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\runke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gpv3h_84\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\AndroidCalc\venv\include\site\python3.8\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.`

I am currently running windows 10 home 64-bit and python 3.8.5

Comment: Can you please paste the full traceback?

Comment: @jakub  https://pastebin.com/zMK6eSjR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [kivy download webpage](https://kivy.org/#download):

> Python 2.7 and 3.5 to 3.7 is supported

Note that Python 3.8 is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created and activated a virtual environment? It solves those problems.

Comment: I ran that inside of a venv environment